# how to insert user login date and time in db using php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I want to insert login date/time in database when user gets login every time.
**This is my model......**

```
public function login(){
    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $result = $this->db->get('auth_user');
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $result->row();
        $data = array(
            'id'        => $result->id,
            'username'  => $result->username,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What You need to insert?

Comment: show Your table where should be inserted `login, date/time`

Comment: Make a field in your database like login_time and when you check user for login if its successful than update login_time to current datetime value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** You need to create a new table where you will insert login logs.

**Step 2:** After session set you can insert.like this:

```
if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $result->row();
        $data = array(
        'id'        => $result->id,
        'username'  => $result->username,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        //insert here
        $this->db->insert('yourtable', array('user_id' => $result->id, 'logintime'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

        return true;
    }
```